# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using this script and getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".

Please help me to get rid of nasty bug, spent lot of time but does not solved.

```
<script>
function endOfText(){
    <?php 
         $free_text = '<div style="display:block;width:600px;height:340px;background-color:black;">
                    <div style="height:35px;"></div>
                    <div style="height:20px;width:600px;text-align:center;color:white;font-size:20px;">PARTIE SUIVANTE</div>
                    <div style="height:30px;"></div>
                    <div style="display:block;width:300px;height:170px;margin-left:150px;cursor:default;
                    background-image:url("'.$server_free.'thumb/'.$drama_tab['shortcut'].'/'.$drama_tab['shortcut'].$epiNB.'-'.$part_1.'_thumb.jpg");background-size:300px 170px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;">
                        <div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_epi('.$part_1.')"><img src="'.$http.'images/next_free.png"/></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height:40px;"></div>
                    <div style="width:600px;text-align:center;color:white;">Ou utilisez les boutons numérotés à droite</div>
                </div>';

    echo '$("#free_video").append("'.$free_text.'");';
   ?>
}
```

Comment: Can I see the JavaScript code in your HTML?

Comment: I also try by removing double quotes then also it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You're printing out 
`echo '$("#free_video").append("'.$free_text.'");';`

Which contains 2x `"` to indicate the string.

While building your `$free_text` you're also setting in `"` for `the background-image:url("/test/myImg.jpg")`

So in the end your error is producted by having something like

`$("#free_video").append("background-image:url("/test/myImg.jpg")");` which, of course, won't work.

Solution: Escape your `"` and/or overthink your usage for `'` and `"`

Comment: should I use like this     echo '$("#free_video").append('.$free_text.');';

Comment: No. This would result in an error as well. You need to rework your $free_text or use maybe `'$("#free_video").append(\''.$free_text.'\');';`